# How to keep location based Apple Watch app up to date?

Tags: apple-watch

According to Apple, iOS apps should not do geocoding while in the background.

However, WatchKit apps are required to have up to date information for their glances. Since a glance should be prepared before being displayed to the user, how do location based apps keep their location information current while keeping in line with Apple policies?

For example, a weather app could geocode the latest location data (retrieved in the background) when the app is opened on iPhone, before being displayed to the user. A watchkit extension for this same app technically isn't allowed to geocode in the background - so when should it do it?